# Same stateless bean in two ears

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, jndi, websphere-7

I have the same EJB module with a bean inside an EAR that is server side and an EAR that is the client side.
Can I have this situation?

[image: ERAs]

Because I'm getting this error http://justpaste.it/gfs3
without understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answer in the stack trace:

```
The short-form default binding 'com.demo.view.RitornaPersonaRemote' 
is ambiguous because multiple beans implement the interface : 
[RitornaPersonaSenzaClientEAR#RitornaPersonaSenzaClient.jar#RitornaPersona, 
RitornaPersonaWebSenzaClientEAR#RitornaPersonaSenzaClient.jar#RitornaPersona]. 
Provide an interface specific binding or use the long-form default binding on lookup.]
```

If you are asking whether you may have same EJB jar in multiple project - the answer is yes you can. However during deployment you have to use long-form JNDI, provide different JNDI name for beans in other module or disable short names. You cannot register two beans under same name.

Long name would be in the form `RitornaPersonaSenzaClientEAR#RitornaPersonaSenzaClient.jar#com.demo.view.RitornaPersonaRemote`

See detailed info here - [EJB 3.0 and EJB 3.1 application bindings overview](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-0-11-3-1-0&lang=en)

**UPDATE**

To disable short names perform the following steps:

- Go to `Application servers > server1 > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom properties`
- Define new custom property `com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.disableShortDefaultBindings` with value `*` to disable short bindings for all apps or `AppName1|AppName2` to just disable short bindings in selected apps.

Example default bindings are shown in SystemOut.log:

```
The binding location is: ejblocal:JPADepEar/JPADepEJB.jar/TableTester#ejb.TableTester
The binding location is: ejblocal:ejb.TableTester
The binding location is: java:global/JPADepEar/JPADepEJB/TableTester!ejb.TableTester
```

And with `disableShortDefaultBindings` property set there is no short form:

```
The binding location is: ejblocal:JPADepEar/JPADepEJB.jar/TableTester#ejb.TableTester
The binding location is: java:global/JPADepEar/JPADepEJB/TableTester!ejb.TableTester
```

There is a bug in the documentation and the correct property is **com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.disableShortDefaultBindings** not <s>com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.disableShortFormBinding</s>

Comment: How can I change JNDI in websphere 7? I looked at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738457/setting-up-a-url-resource-on-websphere-application-server-7-0 but nothing has changed

Comment: In application context I have <jee:local-slsb id="RitornaPersona" 
  jndi-name="java:app/RitornaPersonaSenzaClient/RitornaPersona!com.demo.view.RitornaPersonaRemote"
  business-interface="com.demo.view.RitornaPersonaRemote" />

Comment: Thats fine, but in that case you need to disable short names using JVM custom property - `com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.disableShortDefaultBindings` or define custom names for these beans either through `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` file or through admin console Applications > yourApp > Bind EJB business and then change the names in each application context.

Comment: Hence, you are saying that I have to create a new file called `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` and inserting   `<session name="rp">  
  <interface class="com.demo.view.RitornaPersonaRemote" 
   binding-name="RitornaPersonaSenzaClientEAR#RitornaPersonaSenzaClient.jar#com.demo.view.RitornaPersonaRemote"/>      
 </session> `, am I right?  I tried but I've got the same error, with also "RP".

Comment: I'd first try to disable short names via custom property and see if the error is gone. Should be easier and without any changes to your code.

Comment: I followed this guide http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_6.1.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/xrun_jvm.html?cp=SSAW57_6.1.0%2F1-15-4-381&lang=en and this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_6.1.0/com.ibm.websphere.ejbfep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html?cp=SSAW57_6.1.0%2F5-1-4-1-4&lang=en but nothing

Answer (score 0):

In my case:- i did install abc.ear and xyz.ear both ear was independent do dependency with each other.

I was calling abc.ear using client-lookup but that was giving me

com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object.
[Root exception is com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.AmbiguousEJBReferenceException: The short-form default binding
'com.ejb.abc' is ambiguous because multiple beans implement the interface :
[xyz-ear#rabc-ejb-1.0.jar#abcInrerfaceImpl, rabc-ear#rabc-ejb-1.0.jar

## abcInrerfaceImpl]. Provide an interface specific binding or use the long-form default binding on lookup.]

my Solution was:-

i removed the abc.jar that was inside another application(xyz.ear)
C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\wstemp\92668751\workspace\cells\mypc00Node01Cell\applications\xyz-ear.ear
'

Then solution client-lookup works fine.

To avoid this in future this is better practice to create separate node on your IBM-WAS server and install both application on different node.

So both application component will not mess up.